# Unexpected poor performance with NVMe drives on an X9DR3-F

Tags: raid, performance, nvme

I am experiencing what seems like uncharacteristically low performance from an NVMe SSD stripe in a server.  The hardware is as follows:

- Motherboard: X9DR3-F
- CPU: Dual E5-2650v2
- RAM: 128GB DDR3-1333 UDIMM (16x8GB)
- NVMe drives:  4x MZVLB256HBHQ-000L7 via PCIe expander with bifurcated lanes

`lspci -nvv` shows a 8GT/s x4 link for a device, showing it operating at PCIe 3.0 like the drive wants:  `LnkSta: Speed 8GT/s, Width x4`.  Benchmarks for this drive show it capable of operating around 1.4GB/s writes.

When I try sequential writes to the drive, I get about a third of that performance.  The following showed the 619MB/s during writes, then paused for another 50 seconds, presumably while the data was fully flushed to disk.

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nvme1n1 bs=16M count=1k status=progress
16726884352 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 27 s, 619 MB/s
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
17179869184 bytes (17 GB, 16 GiB) copied, 71.8953 s, 239 MB/s
```

Assuming this was just some quirk of my synthetic benchmark vs someone else's synthetic benchmark, I put all 4 devices into an MD RAID-0 and tried again:

```
$ sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=4 --force --run /dev/nvme?n1
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/md0 bs=16M count=2k status=progress
34191966208 bytes (34 GB, 32 GiB) copied, 57 s, 600 MB/s
2048+0 records in
2048+0 records out
34359738368 bytes (34 GB, 32 GiB) copied, 79.7502 s, 431 MB/s
```

Better, but much to be desired.  If my public-school education math is to be believed, these drives are transferring somewhere between 430x10 and 600x10 megabits per second, so a best-case scenario of 6gbit.  In ideal conditions, I would expect 4x drives in simple all-0's stripe-writes to hit 6GByte, based on synthetic benchmarks from others.  Assuming this was just some limitation of the system, I tested the unrelated 40gbps ethernet card against a different host:

```
$ iperf -c 10.x.x.x -P 4
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 10.x.x.x, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  325 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  2] local 10.x.x.x port 53750 connected with 10.x.x.x port 5001 (icwnd/mss/irtt=87/8948/196)
[  1] local 10.x.x.x port 53754 connected with 10.x.x.x port 5001 (icwnd/mss/irtt=87/8948/132)
[  3] local 10.x.x.x port 53738 connected with 10.x.x.x port 5001 (icwnd/mss/irtt=87/8948/212)
[  4] local 10.x.x.x port 53756 connected with 10.x.x.x port 5001 (icwnd/mss/irtt=87/8948/107)
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  2] 0.0000-10.0027 sec  12.4 GBytes  10.6 Gbits/sec
[  1] 0.0000-10.0180 sec  12.7 GBytes  10.9 Gbits/sec
[  3] 0.0000-10.0179 sec  10.6 GBytes  9.05 Gbits/sec
[  4] 0.0000-10.0180 sec  10.5 GBytes  8.97 Gbits/sec
[SUM] 0.0000-10.0011 sec  46.1 GBytes  39.6 Gbits/sec
```

While this network card has nothing to do with SSD performance, to me it does show that the system is capable of saturating at least a 40gbit link via PCIe, especially since that card is only an x8 link instead of 4x4.  **One thing that may be of note is that the ethernet card is on CPU1_SLOT1, and the SSDs are on CPU2_SLOT4.**  I'm not sure if that would account for the enormous difference in performance though, since SLOT4 is hanging directly off CPU2, and SLOT1 is hanging directly off CPU1.  There is a dual 8GT/s QPI link between the CPUs and no additional switches:
[image: X9DR3-F block diagram]

To me, it's worth noting that read performance is correspondingly low as well.  There is no filesystem overhead here, this is just raw flash & PCIe performance in effect.  This is about the read performance of 4x consumer SATA HDD's in RAID-5 on lesser hardware, so just absolutely unacceptably slow:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/md0 of=/dev/null bs=16M count=8k
8192+0 records in
8192+0 records out
137438953472 bytes (137 GB, 128 GiB) copied, 214.738 s, 640 MB/s
```

Checking `top` during this read operation showed `dd` consuming 100% CPU, 97% of it in system wait.  The other 31 threads were more or less idle.  Where can I start diagnosing the performance issues experienced here?

---

Assuming this was just an issue with DD, I tried again with fio.  I keep the MD device, formatted it XFS allowing it to choose default settings, mounted it, and ran the tests outlined at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/benchmarking-pd-performance :

### Sequential write

```
Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=1348MiB/s (1414MB/s), 1348MiB/s-1348MiB/s (1414MB/s-1414MB/s), io=80.8GiB (86.7GB), run=61368-61368msec

Disk stats (read/write):
    md0: ios=0/710145, merge=0/0, ticks=0/397607236, in_queue=397607236, util=99.82%, aggrios=0/177558, aggrmerge=0/2, aggrticks=0/99452549, aggrin_queue=99465067, aggrutil=99.62%
  nvme0n1: ios=0/177568, merge=0/5, ticks=0/56627328, in_queue=56635784, util=97.96%
  nvme3n1: ios=0/177536, merge=0/1, ticks=0/145315089, in_queue=145331709, util=99.62%
  nvme2n1: ios=0/177559, merge=0/3, ticks=0/151148103, in_queue=151165889, util=99.44%
  nvme1n1: ios=0/177569, merge=0/0, ticks=0/44719677, in_queue=44726889, util=97.87%
```

### Random write

```
Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  WRITE: bw=101MiB/s (106MB/s), 101MiB/s-101MiB/s (106MB/s-106MB/s), io=6074MiB (6370MB), run=60003-60003msec

Disk stats (read/write):
    md0: ios=0/1604751, merge=0/0, ticks=0/623304, in_queue=623304, util=100.00%, aggrios=0/401191, aggrmerge=0/2, aggrticks=0/153667, aggrin_queue=153687, aggrutil=99.99%
  nvme0n1: ios=0/402231, merge=0/3, ticks=0/156754, in_queue=156775, util=99.98%
  nvme3n1: ios=0/401144, merge=0/2, ticks=0/149648, in_queue=149667, util=99.98%
  nvme2n1: ios=0/400158, merge=0/0, ticks=0/150380, in_queue=150400, util=99.98%
  nvme1n1: ios=0/401233, merge=0/4, ticks=0/157887, in_queue=157908, util=99.99%
```

### Sequential read

```
Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=6244MiB/s (6547MB/s), 6244MiB/s-6244MiB/s (6547MB/s-6547MB/s), io=367GiB (394GB), run=60234-60234msec

Disk stats (read/write):
    md0: ios=3089473/14, merge=0/0, ticks=272954324/220, in_queue=272954544, util=99.98%, aggrios=779529/3, aggrmerge=6/1, aggrticks=68744470/104, aggrin_queue=68744621, aggrutil=99.60%
  nvme0n1: ios=779520/6, merge=12/2, ticks=24023533/1, in_queue=24023534, util=98.84%
  nvme3n1: ios=779519/2, merge=14/0, ticks=145571896/378, in_queue=145572449, util=99.60%
  nvme2n1: ios=779536/3, merge=0/1, ticks=77038488/3, in_queue=77038492, util=98.90%
  nvme1n1: ios=779544/3, merge=0/1, ticks=28343963/34, in_queue=28344012, util=98.81%
```

### Random read

```
Run status group 0 (all jobs):
   READ: bw=372MiB/s (390MB/s), 372MiB/s-372MiB/s (390MB/s-390MB/s), io=21.8GiB (23.4GB), run=60002-60002msec

Disk stats (read/write):
    md0: ios=5902401/10, merge=0/0, ticks=2684388/0, in_queue=2684388, util=100.00%, aggrios=1475009/3, aggrmerge=608/0, aggrticks=685706/0, aggrin_queue=685706, aggrutil=99.90%
  nvme0n1: ios=1475288/4, merge=632/1, ticks=697246/0, in_queue=697246, util=99.89%
  nvme3n1: ios=1475328/2, merge=611/0, ticks=678849/1, in_queue=678850, util=99.89%
  nvme2n1: ios=1474625/3, merge=588/1, ticks=673908/0, in_queue=673909, util=99.90%
  nvme1n1: ios=1474795/3, merge=602/0, ticks=692822/1, in_queue=692822, util=99.90%
```

These are much faster, showing there is an advantage to multiple threads beating on the array, but again other benchmarks online showed these drives doing 1GB/s writes individually (whereas I am peaking at 1.4GB/s for all 4 combined), and I've seen UserBenchmark results putting the reads at 2.2GB/s per drive, so 6GB/s reads is doing pretty well in context.

Is there anything to be done to improve single-process performance then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I hate to do it, but ultimately I should answer and close the question.  The PM981 drives *do* have a 512MB DRAM cache, and also offer a 12GB SLC cache, so they should be fast.  Four of them in a RAID-0 should scream.

https://www.techpowerup.com/ssd-specs/samsung-pm981a-256-gb.d784

I just bought a NAS instead, as I never solved this.

Answer (score 7):

Samsung MZVLB256HBHQ-000L7 are small SSDs (256 GB), so you are going to hit the internal NAND bandwidth bottleneck for any writes spanning multiple GB. You can trim them (*losing all data currently stored on the drives*) to clean the internal pSLC cache, hitting more bandwidth for the first benchmarks, but you are going to quickly saturate it again.

Comment: So the solution is: "new drives"?

Comment: If you really need to max out performance - yes, new drives are required. If you can live with the current drives performance - continue using them. And remember that trimming them means *losing all data* already stored on the drives themselves.

Comment: What does "trimming" exactly means in this context? It sounds like taking something off, cutting?

Comment: @OlivierDulac: Modern SSD commands support a `TRIM` command. This tells the SSD which blocks are in use. In this specific case, the intended use it to tell the SSD that _no_ block is in use. This logically restores the SSD to factory state (but not physically - SSD's have a finite number of write cycles, and `TRIM` does not reset that).

Comment: oh ok. Could it be "hiding" defectuous blocks (mark them as valid again) ? or does it only mark as valid and empty all blocks that are not known as defectous?

Comment: @MarkSowul there is no RAID controller, just a card that routes lanes from a PCIe slot to the individual NVMe drives.  Using this card requires support in the BIOS to split a single x16 slot into 4x4 electrical slots sharing a single x16 physical.  The RAID is all in the host OS.

Comment: Ah, yes - I see that now, I'll just delete that comment

Answer (score 1):

My experience with Samsung MZVL* drives is abysmal. See https://superuser.com/questions/1721288/ssd-performance-falls-off-a-cliff

I'm trying to find reputable specs on your drive but my main guess is that the drives are missing DRAM.

Comment: Alright, time to try enterprise drives in my fakey-enterprise situation I guess.

Comment: @BryanBoettcher That's 100% up to you. You are running an Ivy Bridge Xeon after-all... If write-endurance and data loss aren't too big of a concern then go with good consumer-grade option like Samsung 980 Evo Pro. Per the spec-sheet, four 980 Evo Pros will exceed what's capable from a PCIe 3.0 x16 slot.

Comment: Well, I added an Optane P900 and it's better, but not what I expected yet.

Comment: @BryanBoettcher That's an interesting choice considering [Optane was EOL'd](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000059551/memory-and-storage/ssd-management-tools.html) over 2 years ago. There's an old saying, "pay once, cry once" but you seem to be a glutton for hardware punishment =)

Comment: that goes hand-in-hand with me being a cheap-ass.  Cheap came first.

Comment: @BryanBoettcher Third time's a charm =)

Comment: Past Bryan is a sucker, future Bryan is an asshat.  

Anyway, I'm redoing the topology of my setup so the NVMe's are less for caching and more for direct usage.  I have some faith in the drives, since they are enterprise drives (even if old / EoL).  I'm a lot older than those drives are, and I hope I still have some useful life left in me...